# how to receive notifications of incoming group email in sugarcrm

Tags: email, sugarcrm

I have set up a group email account in sugarcane for all user's to use when communicating with customers.  The problem is that to see responses, users have to log into sugarcrm and manually go to the inbox and check.  This leads to messages sitting in the inbox for days at a time without being responded to.

I would just like a simple notification email sent out to all users when a message comes in notifying them that they need to log into sugarcrm and check the email.

Does anyone know some way to do this?
I know there is a sugarcrm forum... but that place is like a black hole where most questions go unanswered, so I thought I'd ask here in case someone happens to see this and have a solution.  :)

(I'm using sugarcrm 6.4.4 pro)